# Ice maker making pounding noise

Tags: ice-maker, ice

I purchased an ice maker from amazon for my Frigidaire side by side.  It woke me up in the middle of the night just pounding.  It seems that the heating element is not getting hot enough fast enough to loosen the ice from the sides of the ice tray.  This is when the fingers that push the ice out of the tray just keep hammering until the heating element gets hot enough to loosen the ice.  Would this be a defective ice maker?

Comment: There really isn't much to an ice maker beyond all of the parts you already suspect. Yes, the ice maker could certainly be defective. It could also be the wrong ice maker, or a wire or connection could be faulty. There are a lot of things to check, but if you suspect the heater, then that is solely electrical and can probably be traced to the wiring harness. Start with that and make sure all of the connections are intact.

Comment: The wiring is correct and the heater does work, it just doesn't get hot enough fast enough.  This unit is the one that comes up when I do a search using the model number of the Frigidaire refrigerator.  I guess the items should be labeled as OEM if they are OEM.

Comment: I did several more searches for refrigerator model number FRS26LF8CWO and found that the ice maker I did order is a Frigidaire manufactured part (OEM).  I think it's just a defective part.  I feel bad that I through the box out before it had a chance to run a couple of days.  The UPS guy was here today ready to pick it up but I didn't have a box.  Service is VERY good.  I'll wait to send the old ice maker back as soon as I get the replacement.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon has a very purchaser-friendly return policy. Many times you won't have to pay return shipping. If you suspect a defect or any faults it would be wise to return the item rather that void the warranty by trying to repair an unknown problem. If you do order another replacement I've learned that it is usually best to purchase an Original Equipment Manufacturers part (if it's a Frigidaire stay with Frigidaire parts). Parts are usually a bit more expensive, but they tend to last longer than generic or "OEM-like" replacements.